# Jenkins EC2 plugin: how to choose different security group

Tags: hudson, amazon-ec2, cloud, jenkins, hudson-plugins

I am trying to use the EC2 plugin from jenkins to launch a slave agaent instance on AWS EC2. However I want to be able to specify my security group and as of right now it forces me to choose default. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

I looked on git and apparently there was a pull request for this feature. I'm not very familiar with it but it did say it was closed so does that mean it never got commited?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's not tested or anything, but my fork has security groups as of today.

https://github.com/jmoses/ec2-plugin

There's also no downloadable .hpi in the repo, so you'd have to build it.  I'll probably upload one at some point, or drop me a message and I can shoot you the one I've got.  Work in progress.